# permanent cookies for downloading

Tags: download, cookies

I sometimes when download from premium websites their cookies expire in about 4 hours. Sometimes I need to pause the download and start again and due to cookie expiration I logout and I have to re-login and refresh download link.Is there any ways to expand that time period or make cookies permanent

Comment: welcome at superuser. Without knowing much about cookies: what sites do you mean, there could be differences between them. If it's really a premium site with good design, then expiration is probably intentional and implemented in a robust way, I don't think that cracking it is easy / good idea (/legal??)

Comment: Editing a cookie isn't illegal. If a site is using cookies to try to secure a website, that's their fault

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what websites you're talking about, a direct answer isn't possible.

I'm going to go through three answers based on three assumptions.

A) Rather than cookies, perhaps the site in question uses session cookies. If you're inactive for 4 hours, they're going to be gone, so occasionally click on something on the website to keep the session alive.

B) You mention you have to "log in again". If, for some reason they really are setting a cookie that lasts 4 hours, you can install a cookie manager. I find [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) to be the best one. Using this manager, you can set each cookie to live for longer.

C) This answer is based on the assumption that the website in question doesn't use cookies at all, but instead simply generates a download link that stops working after a certain amount of time. HOWEVER, this won't interrupt a download that's already taking progress, so this won't be the answer, unless you have a bad internet connection and the download is frequently disconnecting and restarting, which I doubt.

Comment: well these are some great points pointed out by you....will look into it

Answer (score 0):

It may be not enough to persist the cookies! There may be an [Authentication Ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910443) (crypted) in the cookie that determines about expiration time:

**How are cookie expiration and ticket expiration related?**

> In case of non-persistent cookie, if the ticket is expired, cookie
>   will also expire, and the user will be redirected to the logon page.
>   On the other side, if the ticket is marked as persistent, where the
>   cookie is stored on the client box, browsers can use the same
>   authentication cookie to log on to the Web site any time. However, we
>   can use the FormsAuthentication.SignOut method to delete persistent or
>   non-persistent cookies explicitly.
>
> For more information about the FormsAuthentication.SignOut method,
>   visit the following MSDN Web site:
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx